# Passing throwing functions as arguments

Tags: swift, error-handling

I am trying to simply pass a throwing function as an argument to another function, which will then cope with swift's error handling:

```
enum Err: ErrorType {
    case pfui
}

func bad(i: Int) throws -> String {
    if i < 10 {
        return String(i)
    } else {
        throw Err.pfui
    }
}

func handle(@autoclosure f: () throws -> String) -> String {
    do {
        return try f()
    }
    catch {
        return "oh snap"
    }
}


// error: call can throw but is not marked with 'try'
handle(bad(3))
```

It must be something simple that I am missing, but somehow the autoclosure attribute does not keep the compiler from thinking that I am actually calling it.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `rethrows` keyword on `handle` to indicate that if the closure is a throwing function, `handle` will "re-throw" it. If you do that, then you don't need to catch the error inside of `handle`. So it depends on where you want to catch the error:

```
func handle(@autoclosure f: () throws -> String) rethrows -> String {
    return try f()
}

do { 
    try handle(bad(11))
} catch {
    print("\(error)")      // prints "pfui"
}
```

I guess it just depends on where you want to do your error handling. Do you want all errors handled inside of `handle`, or do you want to be able to handle them outside of `handle`?

Comment: The idea was to handle the error inside `handle`, so `rethrows` is not what I was looking for. The code is thinned down to illustrate the problem; in my app I am using the handle function to change the error handling model from swift's `do`/`try`/`catch`, which I dislike, to a `Result`-based model.

Comment: That clarifies things. I'll leave the answer up in case others are interested in the `rethrows` keyword. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Well... eventually found it out myself.

```
handle(try bad(3))
```

does the trick. In hindsight, the compiler was actually telling me what to do for a change. I still cannot figure out why I have to mark the name of a partially applied function with `try` at a place that is not the call site, however.